# Failing to read the response in OkHttp in Andoird O (android 8.0)

Tags: java, android, http, https, okhttp

I am getting exception while waiting for the response from the okhttp library in Android 8.0 and in Android 7.x it is working fine.

I am using

```
compileOnly com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5
```

Source Code snippet :

```
final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(HttpConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON), body);
        final Request.Builder requestBuilder =
                new Request.Builder().post(requestBody).url(completeUrl.toString()).headers(getDefaultHeaders());

        final Request request = requestBuilder.build();

        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.setWriteTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        final Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

below is the exception I received

```
(Java_com_android_org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto_SSL_1read__JLjava_io_FileDescriptor_2Lcom_android_org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto_00024SSLHandshakeCallbacks_2_3BIII+268)
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native method)
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:766)
  - locked <0x0a8dbea5> (a java.lang.Object)
  at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
  at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:87)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:722)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:576)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
  at com.gemalto.odc.common.http.OkHttpService$RetryingOkHttpInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpService.java:230)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
  at com.gemalto.odc.common.http.OkHttpService.sendRequest(OkHttpService.java:95)
  at com.gemalto.odc.profileassistant.internal.job.HttpJob.execute(HttpJob.java:74)
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Can you please try with newer version? `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0")`

Answer (score 0):

The TLS security settings in that ancient version of OkHttp are no longer capable of connecting to your target HTTPS server. Upgrade to a more recent OkHttp.